# How can I edit a .jar file?

Tags: java, mobile, jar

So I have a jar file with one .class file on it. I just need to change some words in the file.
What program should I use?

I want this to work for my phone.

Comment: What do you mean you need to change some "worlds" (words?) in your `.class` file?  You do understand that such files are binary, right?

Comment: They're just zip files, they can be extracted using any zip program, rename it to `.zip` if you can't do it directly.  But it won't help you much, as the code is not in them, Java is a compiled language - editing the .class files is far from easy.

Answer (score 49):

Here's what I did:

- Extracted the files using WinRAR
- Made my changes to the extracted files
- Opened the original JAR file with WinRAR
- Used the ADD button to replace the files that I modified

That's it. I have tested it with my Nokia and it's working for me.

Comment: Gonna test this, but do you know a good .class editor?

Comment: try class editor at Sourceforge

Comment: Didn't work the app installed and so but i can't start it..

Comment: How did you edit .class file without the editor? is it possible to turn the .class to a .java file?

Comment: This is an excellent method to use if you want to add or change a very small amount of code

Comment: you cannot edit file with this method.

Comment: did not work with 7-Zip for me.

Comment: @Vaibhav What if JAR file obfurscated and I have a.class (1kB) and A.class (10kB)? If I press ADD for modified A.class it spoil the old a.class and I will have two a. and A. classes (10kB both). How to get around this?

Comment: You don't even have to use WinRAR. I renamed the file from `name.jar` to `name.zip` and then I extracted it and I was able to see all of the class files

Comment: Instead of extracting the class, open classfile at code editor ex(visual studio) to modify directly

Answer (score 27):

A jar file is a zip archive. You can extract it using [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (a great simple tool to open archives). You can also change its extension to zip and use whatever to unzip the file.

Now you have your class file. There is no easy way to edit class file, because class files are binaries (you won't find source code in there. maybe some strings, but not java code). To edit your class file you can use a tool like [classeditor](http://classeditor.sourceforge.net/).

You have all the strings your class is using hard-coded in the class file. So if the only thing you would like to change is some strings you can do it without using classeditor.

Comment: How do i edit the string, the program don't let me.

Comment: @user: Are you using windows? Open the class file with notepad, search for the string, change it and save. Then put the class file back in the archive.

Comment: It seems ClassEditor doesn't always work properly on newer Java class files. Maybe it's because ClassEditor hasn't been updated since 2007? I tried to edit a simple constants string after extracting the Java class file from a .jar file, and now the Java program fails to run with this error: "LinkageError occurred while loading main class... Wrong InnerClasses attribute length in class file"

Answer (score 4):

> This is a tool to open Java class file binaries, view their internal structure, modify portions of it if required and save the class file back. It also generates readable reports similar to the javap utility. Easy to use Java Swing GUI. The user interface tries to display as much detail as possible and tries to present a structure as close as the actual Java class file structure. At the same time ease of use and class file consistency while doing modifications is also stressed. For example, when a method is deleted, the associated constant pool entry will also be deleted if it is no longer referenced. In built verifier checks changes before saving the file. This tool has been used by people learning Java class file internals. This tool has also been used to do quick modifications in class files when the source code is not available." this is a quote from the website.

http://classeditor.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I assume you know how to open a jar since you know it only has one class file.

Comment: How do i edit, i see the whole thing but i don't know how to edit the strings

Comment: in Windows I created a batch file in the same directory as the class editor jars with `start javaw -jar %~dp0ce.jar %*`