# selenium rc storeEval not working across tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

the `storeEval` command works across test cases within a suite when using the selenium IDE -- (firefox addon)
but the same suite does not work when using the selenium RC (jar)

The variable is not stored

Example

test1

- click
- storeEval "asd" foo

test2

- type element_id ${foo}
- "asd" appears in selenium IDE. However, "foo" appears"  in selenium RC

Any suggestions?

Thank you

PS: Please note this is an htmlsuite running in both selenium IDE & selenium RC

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutionby editing one of the jar files:
http://mumblblog.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/make-store-command-work-with-selenium-rc-to-pass-values-between-test-cases/

about editing the file inside jar:
[How can I edit a .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837500/how-can-i-edit-a-jar-file/4837522#4837522)

It helped for me.