# How can I open .jar files in Eclipse Java EE?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-mars

I just want to ask how can I open .jar files in Eclipse (Jee Mars)...
There is a gif:
[image]

**Please** someone help me :)

Comment: JAR file is also a archive file just like RAR or Zip. Why do you want to open it in eclipse? You're unclear what you are asking. Please clarify the exactly problem with additional information.

Comment: I just want to edit it directly if it possible, I don't want to decompile it and export it...

Comment: If you want to edit the jar file contents, you modify the file and you must recreate the jar. You can't directly edit and save the changes as is. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224817/modifying-a-file-inside-a-jar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837500/how-can-i-edit-a-jar-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit a .jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837500/how-can-i-edit-a-jar-file) or [Modifying a file inside a jar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1224817/1793718)