# WSO2 Dashboard Cant Show Chart

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I've already try to generate gadget from wso2 dashboard, to show data from mysql but i've got error when try to get preview or try to add gadget to dashboard. The error code is :

[2017-11-20 14:59:47,680]  WARN {net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.SizeOf} -  The configured limit of 1,000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph. This can be avoided by adding stop points with @IgnoreSizeOf annotations. Since the CacheManger or Cache  elements maxDepthExceededBehavior is set to "abort", the sizing operation has stopped and the reported cache size is not accurate. If performance degradation is NOT an issue at the configured limit, raise the limit value using the CacheManager or Cache  elements maxDepth attribute. For more information, see the Ehcache configuration documentation.

Is there any misconfiguration at my wso2 data analytic server ?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 DAS Dashboards are based on Apache shindig. This is a warning from ehcache pool of shindig and this should not cause any issue of showing chart in the dashboard.

If you want to avoid printing this issue you need to increase the maxDepth of the ehcacheConfig.xml located inside shindig-common-2.5.2.jar which is included in following path

```
PRODUCT_HOME/repository/deployment/server/webapps/shindig/WEB-INF/lib/shindig-common-2.5.2.jar
```

Inside JAR you can find ehcacheConfig.xml in follwing path

```
org/apache/shindig/common/cache/ehcache/
```

You need to change maxDepth attribute of following element.

```
<sizeOfPolicy maxDepth="1000" maxDepthExceededBehavior="abort"/>
```

Finally you need to save these changed and restart the server.

Comment: just increase maxDepth value ? 
and how to convert extracted jar folder into jar again?

Comment: There are so many ways to do that depending on the operating system you are using. please refer following stack overflow question. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224817/modifying-a-file-inside-a-jar

Comment: i've already change maxdepth and update jar file but when i would like to add my own gadget ..there are no gadget listed like on my screenshot

Comment: As i said before above warning should not cause any issue drawing the chart. What do you mean by own gadget? do you want to generate a gadget from wizard or manually develop your own one?

Comment: i want to build my own gadget, could you attach the library here ?

Comment: Please refer following document
https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Manually+Creating+a+Custom+Gadget

I have written a blog too but content is bit outdated but concepts are still valid
http://blog.tharik.org/2015/09/create-your-own-custom-real-time-gadget.html